# Angular 12 - When I click an already selected tab from mat-tab-link it doesn't reload the page

Tags: angular, mat-tab

I have an application that has a navbar, in that navbar there are several mat-tab-link .
Clicking on one of the links loads a certain page.
When I click a link that is currently focused, it doesn't perform any load/reload of current page/tab.
Currently I have to click on another tab and then click the previous tab in order to "reload" the tab.

```
<div class="app-nav">

  <nav #tabs mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index" [routerLink]="routeLink.link" routerLinkActive
      #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="activeLinkIndex === i" (click)="activeLinkIndex = i" (selectedTabChange)="tabClick()">
      {{routeLink.label}}
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="app-div">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs-compat";

@Component({
    //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: 'app-app-control',
    templateUrl: './app-control.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-control.component.scss']
  })
  export class AppControlComponent {
    routeLinks:any[];
    asyncTabs: Observable<any>;
    activeLinkIndex = 0;

    
    @ViewChild('tabs', {static: false}) tabs;
  realignInkBar() {
    // this.tabs.realignInkBar();
    this.tabs._alignInkBarToSelectedTab();
  }
    
    constructor(private router: Router) {
      this.routeLinks = [
      {label: 'Page1', link: 'page1'},
      {label: 'Page2', link: 'page2'},
      {label: 'Page3', link: 'page3'}]

      this.asyncTabs = new Observable((observer: any) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(this.routeLinks);
        }, 1000);
    
    })
    this.activeLinkIndex =
          this.routeLinks.indexOf(this.routeLinks.find(tab => router.url.indexOf(tab.link) != -1));
    }

    tabClick(){

      console.log("clicked")
    }
  }
```

I don't know what to even try here.

Comment: why would you want to do that? is there a some kind of `:id` parameter in the url of that route?

Comment: In the selected page, there is a table with filters.
so when a user is selecting several filters and wants to clear everything, refreshing the page clears it in a fast matter

Comment: you can do ```(click)``` on the tab to run a function which goes to the certain link probably.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to make the page reload on the same url navigation. but it is only possible to configure this for the whole app, when registering RouterModule.forRoot(...)

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You'r answer was half of the answer.
I had to add the following:
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //  ...
    // With the below line you can now reload the same component from the same route
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => { return false; };
  }